# set cookie for toggle menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie depending on every click on button. I have a button with toggle rule . When user choose open menu-toggle , it should be save cookie for about a week ... The next time (second click ot button - toggle menu is hide) it must change cookie value ...
when cookie value is 1 - menu must be open always, and when value is 2 - menu must be close always ..

button:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li>
        <div class="navbar-btn btn-group">
          <a href="#" onclick="setMenuSm('1')" id='toggle-button' class="topbar-menu-toggle btn btn-sm" data-toggle="button">
          <span class="ad ad-wand"></span>
         </a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the java script:

```
    function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}

function setMenuSm(){
      var cssSelected = $("#toggle-button").hasClass("active");
      if (cssSelected !== true) {
          setCookie("selectedCSS", "menuopen", 3);
      }else{
          setCookie("selectedCSS", "menuclose", 3);
      }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    getCookie("selectedCSS");
    console.log(getCookie("selectedCSS"));
})
```

... now when click load page console give me "menuopen" and when click on button open gray windows like loading and nothing to do...

Comment: where is #toggle-button?  `<butt on` should be button, why is there backslashes in the attrs?

Comment: when i oppen menu, ather jquery add this class "active" on button

Comment: but where is the button you haven't got id="toggle-button" on the button shown

Comment: i am so so sorry ... in comment i will add script of button

Comment: now i edited my post ... this is button code you can see it

Comment: setMenuSm doesnt accpet the value  1

Comment: If you get a working codepen i will get to work on it :) I have a few ideas

Comment: ok i will added and will post the link , thanks

Comment: here is a link : https://codepen.io/EVasileva/pen/KoaYdv

Comment: can you reproduce on that?

Comment: yes i can ... just toggle menu dont open but i white for first time in open code and dont understand why dont accept $ ... is this an obstacle?

Comment: yes it means jquery isn't defined so your code wont work